# Show total of columns in another column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query in which I will enter values dynamically. 
For ex: If I am entering two values `27/1, 151/3` in the textbox.

The query becomes is

```
select area_guntha 
from xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst 
where SURVEY_AREA_7_12 IN  ('27/1', '151/3')
```

which gives me result as `173.3` and `16.7`

The screenshot is below

[image: IMG]

I want to add both these value and show it in another column

**UPDATE**

My query is not fetching the data properly,

The query it should be something like this.

```
SELECT SUM (area_guntha) area_guntha
FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst
WHERE survey_area_7_12 IN ('27/1', '151/3', '87/4')
```

But I am unable to add `' '` after every value
 and it is coming like this

```
SELECT SUM (area_guntha) area_guntha
FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst
WHERE survey_area_7_12 IN ('27/1, 151/3, 87/4')
```

Here is my code

```
string strVal = txt712.Text;

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT SUM (area_guntha)area_guntha FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst WHERE "+
                                          "survey_area_7_12 IN ('" + strVal + "')", conn);

    if(ddlTranType.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Equals("--Select--"))
    {
        txttotalguntha.Value = "";
        return;
    }
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(dr.HasRows)
    {
        dr.Read();
        txttotalguntha.Value = dr["area_guntha"].ToString();
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: How are you adding values dinamically? You have a procedure, use some programming language to call statement? Have bind variable?

Comment: @Kacper: yes the value are been entered dynamically. Sometimes it may be 2, 3 or anything.. YES i have a bind variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 1, :var from dual where 1 = :var;
```

gives value of bind var in another column so:

```
select area_guntha, replace(:bind,',',' ')
  from xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst 
  where SURVEY_AREA_7_12 IN  (:bind)
```

Or I missunderstood and you just want

```
select area_guntha, survey_area_7_12 
  from xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst 
  where SURVEY_AREA_7_12 IN  (:bind)
```

Comment: What i want is, `' '` after every value inserted and i do not get it from your query. SO how can I add that ?

Comment: `replace(:bind,',',', ')` ? @nad

Comment: is your answer updated one, so should I try and check ?

Comment: @nad now it is. Please retry

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I have understood your question properly. With my understanding, you can use below query to get the sum of both values in another column,

```
select area_guntha, SUM(area_guntha) OVER() AS sum_area_guntha
from xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst 
where SURVEY_AREA_7_12 IN  ('27/1', '151/3')
```

This will give you output as

```
area_guntha      sum_area_guntha
173.3            190
 16.7            190
```

Hope this is your requirement